# miniconda scipy

Tags: python, python3

I have installed `miniconda3` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.
When I type which python, it reads:

```
 Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`enter
```

Miniconda3 automatically installs numpy in the path but not scipy.
So I looked at the manual and found this command:

`conda create --name scipy python` and the way to activate it.

But when I use the terminal to import scipy it does not do so.

can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: could post error message relating "But when I use the terminal to import scipy it does not do so."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to install `scipy` using conda is:

```
conda install scipy
```

[conda docs - Managing Packages](https://conda.io/docs/faq.html#managing-packages)

> **Installing packages**
>
> - How can I install a specific package, such as SciPy?
>
>   `conda install scipy`
> - How can I install a package such as SciPy, in a specific version?
>
>   `conda install scipy=0.15.0`
> - How can I install more than one package at once, such as SciPy and cURL)?
>
>   `conda install scipy curl`